# Solving color correction of LISS IV Multispectral image

Tags: color, erdas-imagine, atmospheric-correction, liss-iv

[image]

I have a LISS IV multispectral images (radiometric resolution of 10 bit per pixel) taken in different months 4 tile in January and 2 tiles taken in February.

While mosaicing, I got a different color for the image taken in February while other images taken in the month of January does fine. I tried color correction using histogram matching as well as an image dodging in ERDAS Imagine but not satisfied with the result. Attached is the screenshot of the image.

Is there any way to get past this problem?